# @QueryParam Unbale to fetch the request Paramters

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

i am trying to fetch the request parameters from my url request for a REST Web Service. @Path is able to map the method. But QueryParam is unable to fetch the values from query parameters.

My Request Url is

192.168.20.147:8080/NestRestApi/rest/hello/ScripInfo/MACLEAN1-11365/nse_cm/531335

```
package Rest;


import com.omnesys.nest.classes.CNestQuotes;
import com.omnesys.nest.constants.NESTerror;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.*;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author maclean
 */
 @Path("/hello")
public class ScripInfo {

    /**
     *
     * @param AccountId
     * @param Exch
     * @param Symbol
     * @return
     * @throws ServletException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @GET
  @Path("/ScripInfo/{AccountId}/{exch}/{sym}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML)
  public String getScripInfo(@QueryParam("AccountId") String AccountId,@QueryParam("exch") String Exch, @QueryParam("sym") String Symbol) throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      CNestQuotes oNestQuote = new CNestQuotes();
       oNestQuote.sExchSeg=Exch;
      oNestQuote.sLoginId=AccountId;
      oNestQuote.sSymbol=Symbol;
  HttpServletRequest request = null;
  HttpServletResponse response = null;
            request.setAttribute("QuoteStruct", oNestQuote);

        RequestDispatcher dispatch =request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/NESTGetOMScripInfo") ;
        dispatch.include(request, response);

        Vector oResult = (Vector) request.getAttribute("NESToutObject");

       if (oResult == null || oResult.size() == 0 || oResult.contains(NESTerror.BAD_INPUT) || oResult.contains(NESTerror.NO_DATA) || oResult.contains(NESTerror.MSG_FAILURE)) {
           } else {
                    oNestQuote = (CNestQuotes) oResult.firstElement();
       }

        return null;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AccountId`, `exch` and `sym` are not query parameters but path parameters so instead of `@QueryParam` use `@PathParam`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using QueryParam for AccountId, exch and sym you should use @PathParam.

In JAX-RS, you can use **@PathParem** to inject the value of URI parameter that defined in @Path expression, into Java method.

/users/Query?name=Nasruddin
In above URI pattern, query parameter is "nanme=Nasruddin", and you can get the url value with **@QueryParam**("url")